# Could you theoretically launch your own satellite and transmit satellite phone signals to it?

Tags: communication-satellite

This is a RF and Space question mix, and I am new here and didn’t know where else to ask, so I asked here! This is in the United States btw.

Comment: As far I know, the space is out of the USA jurisdiction. But, to launch a satellite of to the space from U.S. soil requires that the USA (Federal Aviation Authority) allows it. It is probably easier to launch from a lesser bureocratic place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. What would be stopping you besides cost and knowledge? You'd have to make sure the FAA is fine with your plans, so you'd have to demonstrate very well that you know what you're doing & you will do it safely. It's doubtful you'd ever have the time to manufacture your own engines & tanks & avionics & control systems & ground stations by your self, so you'd probably want to put together some sort of company of people to help you out. And rockets are expensive, so you'd likely want to find a way to get investors or otherwise make money to fund this endeavour--unless you're already very rich.

Sound familiar? It's what Jeff Bezos & Elon Musk have essentially done with Blue Origin and SpaceX.

Nobody's stopping you, it's just a hard & expensive thing to do.

Comment: Is it legal with frequency regulations? How much do you think one satellite would cost and how much range would one satellite have?

Comment: I don't know how to answer all of that. Why don't you ask a new question, something more like "How much did the cheapest communications satellite cost" or "how are satellite telephone frequencies regulated"

Comment: @RyanPushkarna it's totally up to you, but generally when we think a question is good enough to accept we also click the up vote button as well. It doesn't cost anything and it's a nice way to say "thank you for your answer".