# How much did the cheapest communications satellite cost?

Tags: communication-satellite

Satellite communication is becoming bigger and better, and I wanted to find out more.

Comment: I think your questions are interesting & you'll enjoy and make good use of this site once you put a little more work into your question posts. I see that [you were advised to post this question separately](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44163/could-you-theoretically-launch-your-own-satellite-and-transmit-satellite-phone-s#comment142720_44166) and followed through, which is great! But maybe you can edit this question and narrow it down to a single answerable question, and consider writing new, separate, carefully written question posts for each of the other parts. *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: Nice edit, retracting close vote.

Comment: Voting to leave open in light of the edit. It is an interesting question now.

Answer (score 4):

The cheapest communications satellite, at least in terms of the cost of the satellite itself, was almost certainly [Echo 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Echo).  I don't have a dollar figure, but the sheer simplicity of the design is hard to beat: it was a 30-meter Mylar balloon that reflected high-frequency radio waves.

Comment: Some nice photos of Echo 1 and Echo 2 at [Did Echo 2 remain spherical without requiring gas pressure? If so, how is this known to be true?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29513/12102)

Comment: Is the moon cheaper?

Comment: Well, we got the moon for free, so I'm pretty sure it is.